# Rails: What is the return type and value of the collection_singular_ids= method in a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

When using a has_and_belongs_to_many association in Rails, it adds a method called `collection_singular_ids=` to the model, where `collection_singular` has to be replaced with the singular name of the associated table.

What is the return type and value of this method? I looked in the [API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many), but did not found it.

Comment: I currently don't have the time to write a full answer. But `collection_singular_ids=` calls `ids_writer` on the association and returns its result. Have a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb#L60-L68 and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L55-L73 or experiment some yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Just go ahead and try it. It returns the array of ids you pass in if successful, nil if not.

Comment: IMO it is not a good documentation, if I have to walk through multiple files of source code to find a return type